# Can we create Cloud server in single Pc (for a learning purpose)

Tags: cloud

I am M.Tech student and reading about cloud computing. I am good in .NET development. 
I want to ask , can I create a cloud server in my winodws server 2008 PC for a learning purpose?

If so, how can I create a cloud server on Pc?

I want to develop program which is secure in a cloud. I also want to create a private cloud for my learnig purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to run a 'cloud-in-a-box'. Both [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) and [Apache CloudStack](http://cloudstack.apache.org/) support this.

For OpenStack, use [devstack](http://devstack.org/). For CloudStack, use [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud)

Apache CloudStack is available as a VirtualBox image, so you can just install VirtualBox on Windows, download the DevCloud image and start it. When you do, give the VirtualBox image as much memory as you can spare, and follow the [DevCloud setup instructions carefully](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud).  The instructions include some important network configuration steps.  If you experience problems, you can contact the [user mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: tHANK YOU VERY MUCH. THIS IS HELP FULL TO ME

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use your PC to host virtual machines if this is what you mean. For example VMware have a free version of their hypervisor and Oracle have VirtualBox (inherited from SUN). More info at:

- http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/
- https://www.virtualbox.org

This would allow you experiment with some of the core technologies used to implement most public and private clouds.