# Software to make your own cloud service?

Tags: cloud

Is there any software that I can install on my server and transform it into a cloud service like RackSpace?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this from Ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/build-a-cloud

Is says

Getting started
Setting up an Ubuntu OpenStack cloud is straightforward.

1 Download Ubuntu Server for cloud

2 Use MAAS to provision your hardware

3 Use Juju to install OpenStack and deploy your services

4 Try Landscape to manage your servers and get support from Canonical

Answer (score 0):

Both Apache Cloudstack and Openstack support single machine deployments. Have a look at this question: [Can we create Cloud server in single Pc (for a learning purpose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890367/can-we-create-cloud-server-in-single-pc-for-a-learning-purpose/18979704#18979704) for more details.